# move textarea box next to text title in form

Tags: html, css

I want to make the text box line up next to 'Additional information' but am not sure how to do this. I have wrapped the labels around the whole input which were only initially wrapped around the title text because I'm getting it ready for some javascript form validation. So I have targeted the text through span tags as you can see in my fiddle.But when I changed things around the text box shifted position.

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/528Wx/

HTML

```
 <form>
 <div class="formColumn2">
 <label for="additionalInfo"><span>Addtional Information</span></label><br>
 <textarea name="comment" form="usrform">Enter text here...</textarea>
 </div>
 </form>
```

CSS

```
 .bookingForm {
height:500px;
background-image:url('images/formpattern.png') 
 }

 .bookingForm img {
width:200px;
margin:90px 0 0 170px;

 }
 /*need to come back to later */
 .bookingForm img:nth-child(3){
margin:240px 0 0 -200px;    

 }

 form {
padding:20px 0 0 70px;
margin-left: 10%;
color:#fff;
 }
 /*this is for text width column2*/
 .formColumn2 label span {
 width: 150px;
 display: inline-block;
 }

 .formColumn1,.formColumn2{
float:left;
 }

 /*aligning top column 2 with title*/
 .formColumn2 {
 margin-top:-80px;
margin-left: 50px;
 }

 /*drop down and input width*/
 select,input{
 width:200px;
 margin:10px 0;
 }

 /*leave*/
 textarea {
 vertical-align: top;
height:110px;
width: 200px;
resize:none;
 }
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, just remove **<br>** present above the *<textarea name="comment" form="usrform">Enter text here...</textarea>*, then the textarea will align next to the *Additional Information*

Comment: I did the same this as @prakash2089 in the fiddle and it fixed the form.

Comment: Hi yes it was the <br> sorry I can't remember why I added it there in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, what you really want. But as per my understanding i create a demo for you -

HTML:

```
<div class="formColumn2">
            <label for="name"><span>Full Name*</span>
                <input type="text" name="name"/>
            </label>
            <br>
            <label for="email"><span>Email*</span>
                <input type="text" name="email"/>
             </label>
            <br>
            <label for="phoneNumber"><span>Phone Number*</span>
                <input type="number" name="phoneNumber"/>
            </label> 
            <br>
            <label for="postalAddress"><span>Postal Address</span>
                <input type="text" name="postalAddress"/>
             </label>
            <br>
            <label for="city"><span>City</span>
                <input type="text" name="city"/>
             </label>
            <br>
            <label for="additionalInfo"><span>Addtional Information</span>
               <textarea name="comment" form="usrform">Enter text here...</textarea>                
            </label>
            <br>
    </div>
```

And CSS :

```
 textarea {
    vertical-align: top;
    height:110px;
    width: 200px;
    resize:none;
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/528Wx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this update **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/528Wx/3/)**

You can use `float`

```
<label for="additionalInfo" ><span style="margin-top:30px;float:left;">Addtional Information</span></label><br>
            <textarea name="comment" form="usrform">Enter text here...</textarea>
```

**CSS**

```
textarea {
    vertical-align: top;
    height:110px;
    width: 200px;
    resize:none;
    float:right;
 }
```

Comment: This one is also right instead i suppose op also have added `br` which will give the solution also 
But this one is also alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Just remove <br> which you have add

<div class="formColumn2">
            <label for="name"><span>Full Name*</span>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            </label>

            <label for="email"><span>Email*</span>
            <input type="text" name="email"><br>
             </label>

            <label for="phoneNumber"><span>Phone Number*</span>
            <input type="number" name="phoneNumber"><br>
            </label> 

            <label for="postalAddress"><span>Postal Address</span>
             <input type="text" name="postalAddress"><br>
             </label>

            <label for="city"><span>City</span>
            <input type="text" name="city">***<br>***<< THis one to remove
             </label>

            <label for="additionalInfo"><span>Addtional Information</span></label><br>
            <textarea name="comment" form="usrform">Enter text here...</textarea>

    </div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/528Wx/4/)**

> The 
>  tag inserts a single line break.
>
> The 
>  tag is an empty tag which means that it has no end tag

Answer (score 0):

Try This HTML Code:

```
<div class="formColumn2">
            <label for="name"><span>Full Name*</span>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            </label>

            <label for="email"><span>Email*</span>
            <input type="text" name="email"><br>
             </label>

            <label for="phoneNumber"><span>Phone Number*</span>
            <input type="number" name="phoneNumber"><br>
            </label> 

            <label for="postalAddress"><span>Postal Address</span>
             <input type="text" name="postalAddress"><br>
             </label>

            <label for="city"><span>City</span>
            <input type="text" name="city"><br>
             </label>

            <label for="additionalInfo"><span>Addtional</span></label>
            <textarea name="comment" form="usrform">Enter text here...</textarea>

    </div>
```